# find the equation of a 'level' curve, for a function $\mu(x_1,x_2)=0$

Tags: curves

I would like to ask the following question.

I have an aggregated function, 
$$
\mu(x_1,x_2) = \|\nabla f_2\| f_1(\vec{x}) + \|\nabla f_1\| f_2(\vec{x}),
$$

where the norm of the gradients are also functions of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

I would like to get the equation describing the curve for which $\mu = 0$.

As an example, for the functions,

$$
f_1 = (x_1 - 3)^2 + (x_2 -3)^2
$$
and
$$
f_2 = \frac{1}{2}(x_1 - 1)^2 + (x_2 - 1)^2
$$

I get,

$$
\mu(x_1,x_2) = \left[ (x_1 - 1)^2 + 4(x_2 - 1)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}  \left[ (x_1 - 3)^2 + (x_2 -3)^2 \right] + 2\left[ ((x_1 - 3)^2 + (x_2 - 3)^2\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \left[\frac{1}{2}(x_1 - 1)^2 + (x_2 - 1)^2\right] = 0,
$$

and I need some function describing the solution, like $\gamma(t)$ or $\gamma(x_1,x_2)$. And it should be goning from $(1,1)$ to $(3,3)$. It would be nice to get a general approach explained, as I want to do this for other more complex functions and with more dimensions. However, I would be happy with the solution to this example since I use it in the report.

(I'am not sure if it is possible or easy, I'am just at a lost and any comment helps.)

Answer (score 1):

Considering  $f_k =\frac 12 (p-p_k)^{\dagger}\cdot A_k\cdot(p-p_k)$ with $A_k > 0$ then $\nabla f_k = A_k\cdot(p-p_k)$ and $||\nabla f_k(p)|| > 0$ for $p \ne p_k$

Resuming,

$$
||\nabla f_1(p)||f_2(p)+||\nabla f_2(p)||f_1(p) > 0\ \ \mbox{for }p_1 \ne p_2
$$

so in those conditions, the solutions for

$$
\mu(p) = ||\nabla f_1(p)||f_2(p)+||\nabla f_2(p)||f_1(p) = 0
$$

are at $p = \{p_1, p_2\}$

Here $p = (x_1, x_2)$

Attached a level curve plot for $\mu > 0$. In red $p_1, p_2$

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing here. Can you tell me what kind of rules you are applying? Or maybe in which category I can find this?

Comment: That is a very nice plot, and yes I understand you now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I tried to simplify the question.

I want to find that curve from $p_1$ to $p_2$ at the lowest point, which I suppost, would be the solution to,

$$
\mu = \frac{1}{\|\nabla f_1(\vec{x})\|} \nabla f_1(\vec{x}) + \frac{1}{\|\nabla f_2(\vec{x})\|} \nabla f_2(\vec{x}) = 0
$$

or is it not possible to use the norms depending on $\vec{x}$?

Comment: In this case , mu  will be a null vector.

Comment: I see, so there is no analitic equation to get the curve between the point?